# my table stays empty when i use it as a subview

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, subview

I'm adding a `UITableView` as a subview to my view; it's a subview because I'm splitting my view into two subviews. I'm new to Objective-C so I am certain it's a rookie mistake.

Here is my code:

```
@interface  DishDetailViewController()
{
   NSMutableArray *_test;
}
@end
```

The `title` property of the object `dish` is an `NSString`.

```
-(void) viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSMutableArray *test = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
   [test addObject:dish.title];
}


- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    self.title = @"Dish Detail";

    UIView *_view = [[UIView alloc]init];
    _view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    self.view = _view;

    int widthTable= 300;

    UITableView *table =[[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, widthTable, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    [self.view addSubview:table];


}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{
    return [_test count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CELL";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];


    cell.textLabel.text = [_test objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    if (cell == nil) 
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    return cell;
}


- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
{
    return 1;
}
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return dish.user;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't set the datasource or delegate of the table:

```
UITableView *table =[[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, widthTable, self.view.frame.size.height)];
table.delegate = self;
table.datasource = self; 
[self.view addSubview:table];
```